# How to add the values from checkboxes to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, checkbox

I have a form that contains a couple of checkboxes. After send this form I would need these checkboxes (the values) to a javascript array.

Could anyone give me a favor, please, how to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var form = document.getElementById("yourformname"),
    inputs = form.getElementsByTagName("input"),
    arr = [];

for (var i = 0, max = inputs.length; i < max; i += 1) {
   // Take only those inputs which are checkbox
   if (inputs[i].type === "checkbox" && inputs[i].checked) {
      arr.push(inputs[i].value);
   }
}
```

Comment: There's an error in your code, the semicolon after the first var statement, making 'inputs' and 'arr' references to global variables.

Answer (score 1):

with jquery you could do something like this:

```
var checkboxArr=[];
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
    checkboxArr.push(this);
});
```

Untested and not sure how this would work in pure js, maybe it can point you in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

```
var values = [],
    inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

for (var i = inputs.length -1 ; i>= 0; i--)
    if (inputs[i].type === "checkbox" && inputs[i].checked)
          values.push(inputs[i].value);
```

for pure JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can test the following function on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZaePM/):

```
function getCheckboxes(form_id, name) {
    // returns array of checked checkboxes with 'name' in 'form_id'
    var form = document.getElementById(form_id);
    var inputs = form.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var values = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
        if (inputs[i].type === "checkbox" && 
            inputs[i].name === name &&
            inputs[i].checked) 
        {
            values.push(inputs[i].value);
        }
    }
    return values;
}
```